# How can i set the parentaccountid in dynamic CRM using Main Data Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am creating a simple console Application in .Net to create a New Account in CRM.For that I am using Main Data WebService and it also created but my question is that i have to set Parent Customer in Account and For that i have to set parentcustomerid in that but i am not getting how can i set it..My code is below.

```
   namespace ConsoleWebService
   {
      class MainDataService
      {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
           Console.WriteLine("New Account GUID="+CreateAccount("Server","New Account"));
           Console.ReadKey();
          }

         private static string CreateAccount(string organizationName, string accountName)
         {
           try
           {

            CrmSdk.CrmService myCrm = new CrmSdk.CrmService();
            myCrm.Url = GetCrmServiceForOrganization(organizationName);
            CrmSdk.CrmAuthenticationToken myToken = new CrmSdk.CrmAuthenticationToken();
            myToken.AuthenticationType = 0;
            myToken.OrganizationName = organizationName;
            myCrm.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = myToken;
            myCrm.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            CrmSdk.account newAccount = new CrmSdk.account();

            newAccount.name = accountName;
            newAccount.address1_country = "India";
            newAccount.address1_city = "Mumbai";

            Guid newAccountId = myCrm.Create(newAccount);
            return newAccountId.ToString();
          }
          catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException soapEx)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("SOAP exception: " + soapEx.Detail.InnerText + " " + soapEx.ToString());
            return soapEx.Detail.InnerText + "  " + soapEx.ToString();
          }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("General exception: " + ex.ToString());
            return "General exception: " + ex.ToString();
         }

    }
    private static string GetCrmServiceForOrganization(string organizationName)
    {
        string urlResult = "";
        CrmSdk.Discovery.CrmDiscoveryService myCrm = new CrmSdk.Discovery.CrmDiscoveryService();

        myCrm.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        CrmSdk.Discovery.RetrieveOrganizationsRequest myRequest = new CrmSdk.Discovery.RetrieveOrganizationsRequest();

        CrmSdk.Discovery.RetrieveOrganizationsResponse myResponse = (CrmSdk.Discovery.RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)myCrm.Execute(myRequest);
        foreach (CrmSdk.Discovery.OrganizationDetail tDetail in myResponse.OrganizationDetails)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Organization = " + tDetail.OrganizationName);
            if (String.Compare(tDetail.OrganizationName, organizationName, true) == 0)
            {
                return tDetail.CrmServiceUrl;
            }
        }
        return urlResult;

    }

}
```

}

Here I can create the new account using above code but i want to set the parent custome in Account so how can i set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Lookup parentAccount = new Lookup();
parentAccount.type = EntityName.account.ToString();
parentAccount.Value = new Guid("GUID of The Parent Account");
newAccount.parentaccountid = parentAccount;
```